# Editing multiple lines for a given file in linux

Tags: linux, rhel7

I have to edit multiple lines in a given file in linux.
Currently i am using sed and awk to edit my configurations file inline.

I tried using sed and awk, both work fine.
But I wanted to know if there are anymore options/command to do the same?

I am new to linux. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you asking how to edit files interactively, or automating it in scripts?

Comment: its actually inside the script. If I have a file named abc.conf then i want to do a string replace in multiple locations. I know how to do this using sed and awk but just wanted to check other options.

Comment: `ed`, `perl`, `php`, `python`, lots of languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **nano** cmd to edit your file simply.
To open a file, pass the filename as an argument:

```
nano ~/public_html/index.html
```

You can also open files at a specific line or column number:

```
nano +LINE /path/to/file
nano +LINE,COLUMN /path/to/file
```

**To open a file as read only:**

```
nano -v myfile
```

**To search for text in a document, use ^W. This will open a search prompt and a submenu of search-related commands.**

- ^G Get Help
- ^Y First Line
- ^T Go To Line
- ^W Beg of Par
- M-J FullJstify
- M-B Backwards
- ^C Cancel
- ^V Last Line
- ^R Replace
- ^O End of Par
- M-C Case Sens
- M-R Regexp

***To save your work, use ^O or “WriteOut”. This will save the document and leave nano open for you to continue working.***

**Use ^X to exit nano. If you have not saved your work, you will be prompted to save the changes or cancel the exit routine.**

> If Nano cmd is not supporting in your OS run above cmd:

**For Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
apt install nano
```

**For CentOS/Fedora:**

```
yum install nano
```

For More Information visit this link [What is Nano Command](http://cartfulldeal.com/Question/Details/1b/what-is-nano-command-in-linux)